# Swift JSONDecoder decode error: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5e48)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-playground

I am trying to decode the below JSON in the Playground, and running into EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Ideally, I would like to decode all properties in the Person struct, but, I can only decode the once those are uncommented right now. As soon as, I uncomment any of the commented once, it throws  *error Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x5e48).*. What am I doing wrong here? I did a lot of Google search, couldn't find any answer.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
struct Address: Decodable {
   var line1: String
   var city: String
   var region: String
   var postalCode: String
   var countryCode: String
}

struct CityCoordinate : Decodable {
   var latitude: Double
   var longitude: Double
}

struct Thumbnail: Decodable {
   var url: String
   var width: Int
   var height: Int
}

struct Headshot: Decodable {
   var url: String
   var width: Int
   var height: Int
   var sourceUrl: String
   var thumbnails: [Thumbnail]?
}

struct Meta : Decodable {
   var id: String
}


struct Person : Decodable {
   //var newPatients: Bool?
   var address: Address
   var description: String?
   var name: String
   var cityCoordinate: CityCoordinate
   //var baseURL: String?
//   var c_baseURL: String?
  // var headhshot: Headshot?
  // var insuranceAccepted: [String]?
   //var expertises: [String]?
  // var meta: Meta
   
   enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
       //case newPatients = "acceptingNewPatients"
       case address
       case description
       case name
       case cityCoordinate
      // case headhshot
      // case insuranceAccepted
       //case baseURL = "c_baseURL"
       //case expertises = "c_expertises"
   }
   
   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
       //self.newPatients = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .newPatients) ?? false
       self.address = try container.decode(Address.self, forKey: .address)
       self.description = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
       self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
       self.cityCoordinate = try container.decode(CityCoordinate.self, forKey: .cityCoordinate)
      // self.insuranceAccepted = try? container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .insuranceAccepted) ?? []
       //self.baseURL = try? container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .baseURL) ?? ""
      // self.headhshot = try? container.decodeIfPresent(Headshot.self, forKey: .headhshot)
      // self.expertises = try? container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .expertises) ?? []
   }
}


let json2 = """
{
   "acceptingNewPatients": true,
   "address": {
       "line1": "111 7th Ave",
       "city": "New York",
       "region": "NY",
       "postalCode": "10005",
       "countryCode": "US"
   },
   "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
   "name": "John Doe",
   "cityCoordinate": {
       "latitude": 41.78200149536133,
       "longitude": -72.83170318603516
   },
   "c_baseURL": "https://some-url.dummy.com/my-profile/current",
   "headshot": {
       "url": "https://some-url.dummy.com/my-profile/current/p/ooREDemnhmfahTVexnEyXRC4GTfeKdCDWgUr-GRL11Y/199x199.png",
       "width": 199,
       "height": 199,
       "sourceUrl": "https://some-url.dummy.com/my-profile/current/p/ooREDemnhmfahTVexnEyXRC4GTfeKdCDWgUr-GRL11Y/199x199.png",
       "thumbnails": [{
           "url": "https://some-url.dummy.com/my-profile/current/p/ooREDemnhmfahTVexnEyXRC4GTfeKdCDWgUr-GRL11Y/196x196.png",
           "width": 196,
           "height": 196
       }]
   },
   "insuranceAccepted": ["Finibus", "anything", "hidden", "consectetur" ],
   "meta": {
       "accountId": "967081498762345229",
       "uid": "Nd28v0",
       "id": "5119-13270",
       "timestamp": "2021-03-24T12:10:36",
       "labels": ["61280", "61288", "84273", "117907", "122937", "126160"],
       "folderId": "351068",
       "schemaTypes": ["therefore", "popular", "commodo", "voluptatem"],
       "language": "en",
       "countryCode": "US",
       "entityType": "informationProfessional"
   }
}

""".data(using: .utf8)!

let person = try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from:json2)
print(person)
```

Comment: Wrap the `try` line in a `do - catch` block and `print` the `error`

Comment: Not reproducible for me, when uncommenting everything (and the missing lines for `meta`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two-three issues I think that is leading to the crash I think, number one is missing meta, number two is there is no `c_expertise` and lastly, when the `Headshot?` is optional in the `init` you need to use `try` instead of `try?` as that is decoding an optional key, after these changes:

```
    struct Address: Decodable {
   var line1: String
   var city: String
   var region: String
   var postalCode: String
   var countryCode: String
}

struct CityCoordinate : Decodable {
   var latitude: Double
   var longitude: Double
}

struct Thumbnail: Decodable {
   var url: String
   var width: Int
   var height: Int
}

struct Headshot: Decodable {
   var url: String
   var width: Int
   var height: Int
   var sourceUrl: String
   var thumbnails: [Thumbnail]?
}

struct Meta : Decodable {
   var id: String
}


struct Person : Decodable {
   var newPatients: Bool?
   var address: Address
   var description: String?
   var name: String
   var cityCoordinate: CityCoordinate
   var baseURL: String?
   var c_baseURL: String?
   var headhshot: Headshot?
   var insuranceAccepted: [String]?
   var expertises: [String]?
   var meta: Meta?
   
   enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
       case newPatients = "acceptingNewPatients"
       case address
       case description
       case name
       case cityCoordinate
       case headhshot
       case insuranceAccepted
       case baseURL = "c_baseURL"
    // case expertises = "c_expertises"
       case meta
   }
   
   init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
       self.newPatients = try container.decodeIfPresent(Bool.self, forKey: .newPatients) ?? false
       self.address = try container.decode(Address.self, forKey: .address)
       self.description = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .description)
       self.name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
       self.cityCoordinate = try container.decode(CityCoordinate.self, forKey: .cityCoordinate)
       self.insuranceAccepted = try? container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .insuranceAccepted) ?? []
       self.baseURL = try? container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .baseURL) ?? ""
       self.headhshot = try container.decodeIfPresent(Headshot.self, forKey: .headhshot)
       //self.expertises = try? container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .expertises) ?? []
       self.meta = try container.decodeIfPresent(Meta.self, forKey: .meta)
   }
}


let json2 = """
{
   "acceptingNewPatients": true,
   "address": {
       "line1": "111 7th Ave",
       "city": "New York",
       "region": "NY",
       "postalCode": "10005",
       "countryCode": "US"
   },
   "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
   "name": "John Doe",
   "cityCoordinate": {
       "latitude": 41.78200149536133,
       "longitude": -72.83170318603516
   },
   "c_baseURL": "https://some-url.dummy.com/my-profile/current",
   "headshot": {
       "url": "https://some-url.dummy.com/my-profile/current/p/ooREDemnhmfahTVexnEyXRC4GTfeKdCDWgUr-GRL11Y/199x199.png",
       "width": 199,
       "height": 199,
       "sourceUrl": "https://some-url.dummy.com/my-profile/current/p/ooREDemnhmfahTVexnEyXRC4GTfeKdCDWgUr-GRL11Y/199x199.png",
       "thumbnails": [{
           "url": "https://some-url.dummy.com/my-profile/current/p/ooREDemnhmfahTVexnEyXRC4GTfeKdCDWgUr-GRL11Y/196x196.png",
           "width": 196,
           "height": 196
       }]
   },
   "insuranceAccepted": ["Finibus", "anything", "hidden", "consectetur" ],
   "meta": {
       "accountId": "967081498762345229",
       "uid": "Nd28v0",
       "id": "5119-13270",
       "timestamp": "2021-03-24T12:10:36",
       "labels": ["61280", "61288", "84273", "117907", "122937", "126160"],
       "folderId": "351068",
       "schemaTypes": ["therefore", "popular", "commodo", "voluptatem"],
       "language": "en",
       "countryCode": "US",
       "entityType": "informationProfessional"
   }
}

""".data(using: .utf8)!

do {
let person = try JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from:json2)
print(person)
} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

It prints `Person`, please give it a try and if throws any error, try in a project instead of `Playground` or online compiler.

Comment: Thanks for response! I ran your code in Playground, and getting this message, valueNotFound(__lldb_expr_39.Person, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data did not contain a top-level value.", underlyingError: nil)).

Comment: Okay, I tried the same here on : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_swift_online.php and it is working fine for me. I'll check in Playground after sometime.

Comment: in a real project it works. Of course, it works in the tutorialpoints.com as well. I am going to accept your answer. Thanks!